# Is there any way to import .xlsx file into nodejs with mongodb as database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Need to import the .xlsx file to my node server. Currently using "xlsxtojson" module to convert but my main problem is that the path needs to be a string, which is where i am stuck.

```
var xlsxtojson = require("xlsx-to-json");

xlsxtojson({
       input: 
   }, function(err, result) {
       if(err) {
           res.json(err);
       }
       else {
           console.log(result);
       }
   })
```

Comment: From where do you want to import the .xlsx from? How is MongoDB related in your question?

Comment: Are you trying to upload file it from front-end ???

Comment: @AmolBJamkar Yes

Comment: @Sreehari I need to save it to MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save that file in the directory using `fs.writeFile`

```
const FILE_PATH = "yourDirectoryPath";
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(FILE_PATH, file, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  convert();
});
```

Now use the same path in the following function

```
const convert = () => {
xlsxtojson({
       input: FILE_PATH
   }, function(err, result) {
       if(err) {
           res.json(err);
       }
       else {
           insertoDb(result); // calling insertDB function after it converts into json
       }
   })
}
```

Now you can loop the array in `insertoDb` function to insert all data into `MongoDB` one by one or bulk `insert`,

```
const insertoDb = (array) => {
   // your insert query using `insertMany`
}
```

Hope this will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Should I use multer for it or not ?

Comment: You can, it depends on you.

Comment: Can you help me on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864278/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined-in-nodejsmulte