# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined' in Nodejs(Multer)

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload the file but there is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined'. Is there any way to solve this?

```
exports.postimport = function (req,res) {

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads');
},
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
}
});

 var upload = multer({
 storage: storage,
}).single('sheet');
 upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err)
       } else {
        console.log(req.file.path);
       }
});
}
```

Comment: can you console log `req.file` and check file is present or not.

Comment: It is undefied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you might be getting path of undefined may be that your destination directory (i.e path to your uploads folder) is not correct.

Comment: Even console.log(req.file) is giving undefined

Comment: Since req.file is undefined, you are likely to get the error "path of undefined". How are you sending the file? Is it through Postman?

Comment: Also have you checked if the 'uploads' in your multer destination function is pointing the correct directory?